# Proper way to fill vector passed by reference

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Say you are implementing a function that receives a reference to a vector that is to be filled:

```
func(std::vector <T> & vec) { ...
```

Now, the function is going to resize and fill this vector, but we don't really know what the vector had inside it previously, or what it's capacity was. To be really safe, one could write:

```
vec.clear(); 
vec.resize(...); 
vec.shrink_to_fit();
```

Is this really necessary, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: how does function "know" what size should new vector have? Is this a parameter to a function?

Comment: The `resize` shouldn't be needed if you're filling the vector via `push_back`, `emplace_back`. If you know the end-size a `reserve()` would be warranted, but avoid `resize()` unless you intend (and rely on) value initialization of the elements. When finished your *request* for a `shrink_to_fit` *may* be fulfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you will overwrite every element (or don't mind untouched elements being garbage), you don't need to clear the vector before resizing. The exception is if you want to fill the whole vector with a default value provided to resize, in which case you do need to clear it.

Usually you pass the vector by reference to save memory allocations by taking advantage of the existing reserved capacity. Using `shrink_to_fit` defeats that purpose, as the vector capacity can go up and down (if the compiler does anything for a shrink). If you want to minimize memory, return a fresh vector by value.

Comment: I suggest to leave the decision of shrinking to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about the previous content, just return by value, you will have copy elision on new variable and move semantics otherelse.

```
std::vector <T> func();

// later
auto vec = func(); // will use copy elision and Return Value Optimisation
existingVec = func(); // move semantic, previous content will be released and new one will be steal from the temporary
```

If you care about the previous content, or at least wants to prevent a dynamic allocation if the previous array capacity is enough, `resize` should be enough

Comment: To be fair, while in the function, there exist two vectors at the same time. This isn't perfectly performant (but might be not relevant for most usecases), and wasteful on memory (but might be not relevant for small vectors)

Answer (score 0):

> implementing a function that receives a reference to a vector that is
>   to be filled

There is no difference between the logic which you can write inside the *func* and inside the function where *std::vector* has actually created and passed as reference to *func*. Both are fundamentally the same and safe.

Comment: I think OP asked more for idiomatic language usage (especially avoiding boilerplate and interface bloat) than for theoretical equivalence.